# Access to private feed from Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to create access to my private feed from pipeline (Project A), but everytime when i try run `dotnet restore` to restore .net project with nugets from private feed (project scoped feed in Project B) i got

```
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source <<url_to_my_feed>>
```

My pipeline.yml looks like:

```yaml
[previous jobs]

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build image
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    repository: $(contentHostRepositoryName)
    Dockerfile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/modules/content/src/Dockerfile"
    arguments: '--build-arg PAT=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'
    tags: |
       $(tag)

[next jobs]
```

My dockerfile looks like:

```yaml
...
ARG PAT
RUN dotnet nuget add source <<url_to_my_feed>> --name <<name>> --username <<username>> --password $PAT --store-password-in-clear-text
...
```

When i replace `'--build-arg PAT=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'` to `'--build-arg PAT=<<pat_token>>'` where `<<pat_token>>` is token, who i generate manualty to my personal account in Azure Devops - everythink work fine.

What i try:

- using $(System.AccessToken) instead $(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)
- in feed set contribution permission to Project A Build Service
- in project B disable `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` and `Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines`
- use `NuGetAuthenticate@0` and `NuGetAuthenticate@1`
- into Pipelines Security in Project A allow Project Build Service for everythink
- before using $(System.AccessToken) main into varaible

Comment: It is supposed to be FEED_ACCESSTOKEN i.e. arguments: '--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'

Comment: What does it matter if i call arg PAT or FEED_ACCESSTOKEN? I supposed that I might as well call it a TEST_TOKEN token, it's important to refer to the correct name in the docercompose file.

Comment: What more, i replace $(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN) manuał create PAT token and everythink work fine

Comment: You are right. The dockerfile also has the same name as ARG so it won't matter.

Comment: What is the username when it is access token? Try "vsts" as username when access token is used.

Comment: Username is doesn't matter. Username can be anything

Comment: Hi Adam, any update on this issue, have you checked my answer? does it answer your question?

Comment: @AdamWróbel Did you ever get this working using the agent PAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `Project Collection Build Service (Organization)` and let it has related permission.

[image]

Since you use yml file pipeline, and you disable `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`, so project build service account  will change to project collection build service account.

And please use  $(System.AccessToken) to auth.